# Is a property default value of null the same as no default value?

Tags: php, properties, null, default-value

And can I therefore safely refactor all instances of

```
class Blah
{
    // ...
    private $foo = null;
    // ...
}
```

to

```
class Blah
{
    // ...
    private $foo;
    // ...
}
```

?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

#### Untyped properties

Simple answer, yes. See http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.null.php

> The special NULL value represents a variable with no value. NULL is
> the only possible value of type null.

You can easily test by performing a `var_dump()` on the property and you will see both instances it will be `NULL`

```
class Blah1
{
    private $foo;

    function test()
    {
        var_dump($this->foo);
    }
}

$test1 = new Blah1();
$test1->test(); // Outputs NULL


class Blah2
{
    private $foo = NULL;

    function test()
    {
        var_dump($this->foo);
    }
}

$test2 = new Blah2();
$test2->test(); // Outputs NULL
```

#### Typed properties

PHP 7.4 adds typed properties which do not default to `null` by default like untyped properties, but instead default to a special "uninitialised" state which will cause an error if the property is read before it is written. See the "Type declarations" section on the [PHP docs for properties](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php).

Comment: Also note that with `error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);` you cannot define variables the way `$var;`, but you can define properties in a class the way `public $var;` (or protected or private).

Answer (score 11):

> Is a property default value of null the same as no default value?

## Yes

<sub>[as per the docs:](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.null.php)</sub>

> The special `NULL` value represents a variable with no value.

`null` is a concept of a variable that has not been set to any particular value. It is relatively easy to make mistakes when differentiating between `null` and empty<sup>1</sup> values.

`private $foo = null;` is exactly equivalent to `private $foo;`. In both cases the class attribute is defined with a value of `null`.

`isset` will correctly return `false` for both declarations of `$foo`; `isset` is the boolean opposite of `is_null`, and those values are, as per above, `null`.

For reference, I recommend reviewing the [PHP type comparison tables](http://php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php).

<sub>1: In this case I am referring to typed values that return true for the [`empty`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) function, or which are otherwise considered "falsey". I.E. `null`, `0`, `false`, the empty array (`array()`), and the empty string (`''`). `'0'` is also technically empty, although I find it to be an oddity of PHP as a language.</sub>

Answer (score 5):

Apart from the accepted answer that is still true, with the addition of typed properties in PHP 7.4 there are new things to consider.

Given the following code

```
class A {
    public ?DateTime $date;
}

$a = new A();
$a->date;
```

You will get the error

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Typed property A::$date must not be accessed before initialization

That means that the property `$date` is not automatically initialized with `null` even though this would be a valid value. You'll have to initialize it directly like `public ?DateTime $date = null;` or use the constructor to do so.

Comment: Thank you! I think the accepted answer is not correct now since it only applies to untyped properties. A correct answer should cover both typed and untyped properties since the question didn't specify.