# Is it NOT actually mandatory to set a value to a property in PHP class?

Tags: php, class, object

I have following PHP class:

```
<?php
class Fruit
{
    public $name;
    public $color;

    public function __construct($name, $color)
    {
        $this->color = $color;
    }

    public function intro()
    {
        echo "The fruit is {$this->name}, the color is {$this->color}.";
    }
}

$apple = new Fruit("Apple", "red");
$apple->intro();
?>
```

Above code gives me following output:

```
The fruit is , the color is red.
```

I get to the point straightway that why above code is NOT throwing any error for `$this->name`?

I am not setting up any value to `$this->name` property as I don't have:

```
$this->name = $name;
```

Then how it is set to an empty string i.e. `''` automatically?

However, when I remove the line `public $name;` then I obviously get error:

```
Notice: Undefined property: Fruit::$name
```

I am confused a bit, please explain.

Comment: Any properties will have a default value of null.

Comment: Oh really! I never knew. In procedural coding, it defaults to undefined. Please provide me a link that highlights this point.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14097258/is-a-property-default-value-of-null-the-same-as-no-default-value shows how not setting a value is the same as being set to NULL specifically.

Comment: However, that only goes for untyped properties. If you have a typed property without a default value, it will throw an error if you try and read from it before you've assigned it a value.

Comment: Dynamic properties are deprecated as of PHP 8.2.0 https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From PHP [NULL](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.null.php)

> Undefined, and unset() variables will resolve to the value null.

From PHP [echo](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.echo)

> Non-string values will be coerced to strings, even when the `strict_types` directive is enabled.

So the variable is rendered as the empty string.